# Android Seekbar with progress view

Tags: android, custom-controls, seekbar

I want to create a SeekBar like below.
[image]
Its main feature who i care is that user can seek in specified range not whole range of SeekBar, like what happens when watching movies while its download is still in progress.
In above seekbar user can move thumb in range highlighted with dark gray, and range displayed with light gray is not seekable.
i would be thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int progress = progressBar.getProgress();
if(progress>desiredProgress){
progressBar.seekTo(desiredProgress);
}
```

EDIT:

set:

```
 int desiredProgress = progressBar.getSecondaryProgress();
```

Comment: you get to the dark grey with progressBar.getSecondaryProgress();